# Android: How to stop Thread.sleep in an IntentService from the MainActivity

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am developing an Android App. I have a `MainActivity` class where I launch an `IntentService`.

In the `IntentService` class, I use `Thread.sleep` in the method `onHandleIntent` to handle a necessary `pause`.

Everything works fine.

What I would like to do is have a button in the `MainActivity UI` which can interrupt the `Thread.sleep` in the `IntentService`.

Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have Some code?

Comment: i think you cant do anything when intentservice already run

Comment: Thank you. That was what I thought, but couldn't find it written down clearly enough for me. If I could vote, I would give patwanjau the points.

Comment: Skynet - the code would be too long, but it's simply a MainActivity class that launches an IntentService when a button is pressed. The IntentService has a method onHandleIntent, in which I call Thread.sleep. I'd like to make it sleep for a minute or two, but to let the user 'interrupt' the thread.sleep when they press a cancel button in the UI. I'll do it a different way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You cannot handle non UI related threads from the main UI thread. A thread is an independent entity when it's executed. If you want to be able to cancel a task that is already running, you should consider using `AsyncTask` and implement the `doInBackground()` method. Thereafter, it's possible to cancel this task from the UI if it's still executing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to consider using a `Service` instead of the `IntentService`. The first one doesn't stop automatically, meaning it will listen to your commands you could send to it (I would go with EventBus) unless it is destroyed by the system to reclaim resources. Still you should definitely stop it on your own after you don't need it.

Anyways, I would better implement `start/pause` feature to control your flow rather than rely on thread interruptions.